Libcurl multi-interface: curl is reusing HTTP connections even if the headers of the easy handlers are different
I have an application that needs to do some HTTP GET requests to some server. However, before doing any GET request, I need to first do an HTTP POST request to the same server to get a token, and with that token, then doing the GET requests, adding the token as a header.
However, since I'm using the curl multi-interface, CURL is reusing the HTTP connection that was established for the token to do the next HTTP GET requests, which doesn't contain the token as header, causing the server to reject my request (because the token is not present).
If I do multiple HTTP GET concurrent requests just after getting the token, all but the first query succeed. Why? Because after the POST request is completed, there's one free connection available in the pool (with the old headers, that doesn't contain the token). So the first GET request reuses it, while the following ones establish new connections, using the headers established for these easy handlers, which contains the correct token.
Illustrative example:
CURLM* mh = curl_multi_init();

CURL* h = curl_easy_init();
curl_easy_setopt(h, CURLOPT_POST, 1L);
curl_easy_setopt(h, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60L);
curl_easy_setopt(h, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, &my_write_function);
curl_easy_setopt(h, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, my_buffer);
curl_easy_setopt(h, CURLOPT_URL, "https://blabla.com/token_requests");
curl_easy_setopt(h, CURLOPT_COPYPOSTFIELDS, "complex data with user, passw and others");

CURL* h_next = curl_easy_init(); // I create the GET requests, and add the token later
curl_easy_setopt(h_next, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60L);
curl_easy_setopt(h_next, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, &my_other_write_function);
curl_easy_setopt(h_next, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, my_other_buffer);
curl_easy_setopt(h_next, CURLOPT_URL, request_url);
curl_easy_setopt(h_next, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BEARER);

curl_multi_add_handle(mh, h);
curl_multi_perform(mh, &running_handles); // call several times, etc
// ...
// when the transfer is done, I parse my_buffer to get the token and then

curl_easy_setopt(h_next, CURLOPT_XOAUTH2_BEARER, token);
curl_multi_add_handle(mh, h_next);
curl_multi_perform(mh, &running_handles); // call several times, etc

When the transfer is done, what I get is a 401 HTTP CODE together with an error message from the server telling the request has no token in it. However, if I add CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE to the token request, like:
CURLM* mh = curl_multi_init();

CURL* h = curl_easy_init();
// ... same options as before...
curl_easy_setopt(h, CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE, 1L);

CURL* h_next = curl_easy_init(); // I create the GET requests, and add the token later
// ... same options as before...

curl_multi_add_handle(mh, h);
curl_multi_perform(mh, &running_handles); // call several times, etc
// ...
// when the transfer is done, I parse my_buffer to get the token and then

curl_easy_setopt(h_next, CURLOPT_XOAUTH2_BEARER, token);
curl_multi_add_handle(mh, h_next);
curl_multi_perform(mh, &running_handles); // call several times, etc

Then it works fine.

I'm surprised that libcurl doesn't take into account important headers that are relevant for the connection. Is that intented behaviour or a "bug"?
Another thing that I observed is that, if I wait 15 seconds between the token request and the first GET request, then the GET request does succeed, which means that there's some timeout somewhere that closes the former connection after 15 seconds of inactivity. However, I haven't seen any of the libcurl options regarding timeouts that have a default value of 15. How can I check/verify if the remote server is who is closing the connection, or if it's my curl client?
Finally, the token has some expiration time where I have to get a new token. However, I'm in the same situation, if the token has expired and I get a new one, any subsequent GET requests that should use the new token, could be using the old one because of connection reuse. What is the best way to prevent that? I guess it's by using the share interface but I'm unsure how exactly.


To see more, run your program under strace. You already have a solution: use CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE But ... I'd put the POST code in a separate function (e.g. get_my_token) that does not use *_multi_* but does curl_perform. Don't add h to mh. You have a subset of the general case where the server that you POST to get the token is the same as the server that handles the GET requests. In the general case, they are different. So, design it that way. Since tokens et. al. are server specific, curl doesn't know what to preserve or not--you have to do that.

And, I would want separate streams for the POST (that has [secret] login/pw info) from the GET that should only need the temporary token. A multi connection might not leak the login/pw to the GET request, but I'd use separate streams to ensure this. This also ensures the serialization that is needed (i.e. you guarantee you have the token before issuing the GET requests). And, when the token is about to timeout, you close the multi connection (flushing requests), then call get_my_token to get a new one and start a new multi connection with the new token.

@CraigEstey The code I presented is illustrative. It's not actual code and the functional decomposition of my actual program is not present at all. I presented a code that is simple enough to illustrate my question.

So, most of what I said still holds. Use strace. I'm surprised that libcurl doesn't take into account important headers that are relevant for the connection. Why would [you want] curl to copy data from https://blabla.com/token_requests to request_url? This would be leaking info. And, again, does request_url need the pw info (or not). How does curl know what to copy or not? AFAICT, keeping the POST separate solves all three of your last paragraphs/questions.

@CraigEstey It's not about what to copy. A simple hash of the values of some important headers, or better said, CURL_OPT_X options, is enough. If the hash of the "options that change the properties of the connection" (like CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH and/or CURLOPT_XOAUTH2_BEARER, and all timeout options, etc) doesn't match a connection in the pool, then that connection can't be reused for this particular request. Also, the token request is using the multi interface because I don't want any blocking operation. Regarding the issue of the expired tokens, I will use de share interface I think.

No such hash exists. Nor would we want one. Each CURL is completely separate from another one. CURLM is just a queue of such CURL. It doesn't copy/move/cache internal data from one to another. CURLM has CURLMOPT_* and knows nothing of CURLOPT_* (which go into CURL) Assuming you already have the auth token (via h_post, you can fill a GET request with it (e.g. h_get), do curl_multi_add_handle, process it, then curl_multi_remove_handle. You can then just change only fields you want to change, and then curl_multi_add_handle to requeue/reuse it.

(e.g.) If you had to do 100 GET for a given server with only minor tweaks, you could maintain your own per-host cache of mostly-filled requests. (e.g. You create 10 with curl_easy_init and reuse them as needed to fulfill the 100). CURLM will not do this for you. This is something you'd maintain external to curl_multi_*

As to your original code, you have a race condition. You create a CURL request with POST to get the token. Then, add it to the CURLM. Then, you create several/many CURL instances with GET in them that all need the token value and add them. Then, you do a perform. There is no guarantee that the POST will either start or complete before any number of the GET requests are started. So, even if the callback for the POST were to try to fill in the auth token(s) for the GET blocks, it would be racing. Your first GET "lost" the race, and the others "won" it. But, it needs a redesign.

h_next, which needs the token, isn't added to the multihandler until the token is received. It's explained in the comments (//when the transfer is done...). Please, that's not actual code, it's illustrative code to understand the nature of the problem. I added code just to make it a bit more readable instead of 4 o 5 ugly walls of text. The textual explanations are actually enough to understand the problem for those that know how curl works. Please focus on my question, not design details that are irrelevant for the question.
